# jquery, continue the reading after html() call

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following Javascript code:

```
o_value.html();
```

give me

```
<span id="legaloffice_city_value">some text</span>
```

All that I want now is to modify, javascript code, to just get: `legaloffice_city_value`. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
o_value.find("span")[0].id
```

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6wUsT/

the reason that we are using the `[0]` part here is that the jquery `find()` function will return a collection of all matched elements according to the selector provided (in our case, the `span` tag name).

so we should use the indexer to access our item inside the collection.
give it a try and let me know

Comment: You might want to explain what the `[0].id` part does / means.